# Merge two dataframe on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the two df as following:

### Df 1:

```
Student ID    Idclass
  
  1,           1   
  2,           2   
  3,           1   
  4,           1
```

Df 2:

```
IdClass         Class
  
  1,              A1
 
  2,              A2
```

---

Desired Output

```
StudentId       IdClass    Class

1,                 1,         A1

2,                 2,        A2

3,                 1,        A1

4,                 1,        A1
```

I think I should merge these df but Idk how.

Comment: looks like you need to merge on the numeric aspect of df2 - what issues have you had so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['IdClass'], how='left')
```